# How does dependency injection know which type of mapping to use when injecting an interface

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, autofac

I've been reading up on dependencey injection and I read a lot on how an interface is inejected through a constructor. How does it know what type of mapping to use for the interface?  For example,  if I have a  service named  ProtienService  and aanother service named  VitaminService that both implement an interface named ISupplement Service and then I can inject a ISupplement Service into my  controller for example, but I'm not  sure how it knows whether to use Protein or VitaminService. Does this just  depend on  the type of ioc that is used? Any advice is appreciated because I'm  a little confused on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell the container what to use. So in Structuremap:

```cs
For<ISupplement>()
      .Use<VitaminService>();
```

Tells the container to use VitaminService when ISupplement interface is used.

You can register multiple implementations:

```cs
For<ISupplement>().Use<VitaminService>().Named("V");
For<ISupplement>().Use<ProteinnService>().Named("P");
```

But in this case you need to tell the container which implementation you want:

```cs
Container.GetInstance<ISupplement>("V");
```

Comment: Cool I didn't know you could do that..isn't this more of a service locator type approach than a dependencey injection approach?

Comment: @tman - Autofac have support for injection based on additional metadata (like Name) and so you won't have to access the container directly.

Comment: @TMan It only becomes service locator when you have more than one actual resolve call on your container. As long as you only use the different named registrations during the container setup, you're not compromising the DI principle.

Comment: After configuring your container, you bootstrap it from your composition root. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/